# Kernel modules missing after update to 5.4.0-37

Tags: wireless, kernel, updates, bluetooth, atheros

I have a Dell XPS with Ubuntu 20.04 and kernel 5.4.0-33 smoothly running.

I've updated the kernel as suggested by the normal update process, but after rebooting the kernel is missing some modules, mainly the network ones (`ath10k` for wifi, and bluetooth too). `sudo modprobe ath10k` answers with a fatal error saying that the module file is missing.

I've attempted to `update-initramfs` by hand but nothing changed, so I had to go back using the previous version, 33.

What can I do to understand and fix the issue?

As requested by comments, info about my system:
 * I have installed 20.04 cleanly (no upgrade) and with full disk encryption

This is my wifi card under 5.4.0-33:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
        Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

[UPDATE] Under 5.4.0-37 the `Kernel modules` and `Kernel driver in use` entries are obviously missing, but the card is listed twice and a lot more other modules are missing (`i915`, `processor_thermal_device`, `intel_pch_thermal`, 
`intel_lpss_pci`, 
`mei_me`, 
`snd_hda_intel`, 
`nouveau` (but not the nvidia, which I'm using), 
`ath10k_pci`, 
`rtsx_pci`). You can look at the full `lspci` diff here: https://www.diffchecker.com/mVCbTzSL

I've also opened a Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1883239

This is the modules that are present, notice that the module is missing for the `37` kernel:

```
$ find /usr/lib/modules -iname ath10k  
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k
```

Comment: separate /boot filesystem? `df -h; df -i` please.

Comment: @nobody I've added the info in the question, thank you.

Comment: wrong system in my mind.  `find /usr/lib/modules -iname ath10k_*` then you can see available modules for Atheros wlancards.   for network cracks please  (not me) `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` or if it is an usb device `lsusb` please.
`

Comment: @nobody question updated, the module is effectively missing for the newer kernel.

Comment: this `ath10k_pci` is your module for the wlancard and it is loaded. Do you have problems with you internet connection?

Comment: @nobody not now but I rebooted under the 33 kernel to get the network back. IIRC under 37 `lspci` said `disabled`

Comment: Might be related to the previous broken intel-microcode release that was released at the same bug. Although it has been since reverted, I also still need to boot with the 33 kernel, as with the 37 kernel networking is broken for me, too: https://askubuntu.com/a/1248853/117753

Comment: FTR, I've opened a bug on Launchpad; I'll edit the question with the same infos.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but using 18.04 lts. After installing 5.4.0-37 from apt, a specific package was not installed and I couldn't get Atheros kernel module.

I switched back to my working kernel and installed manually all other 5.4.0-37 packages found on repo. The Atheros wireless driver is in this one:

```
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-37-generic
```

This is for 18.04 LTS; but maybe it also solve for 20.04 LTS. BTW, I've installed a fresh Kubuntu 20.04 LTS yesterday and the update to 5.4.0-37 worked fine, including Atheros wireless driver (ath10k*).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. That package should be present as a dependency of the linux-modules-extra-generic metapackage, I'll check if that's present.

Comment: I had a similar issue with HDMI port in my notebook after update to 5.4.0-37 and this resolved! Tks.