# Boot: Ubuntu 20.04 not booting: timed out waiting for device

Tags: boot, kernel, 20.04

I updated the kernel of my Ubuntu 20.04 to 5.4.0-37-generic and when I reboot the system I always got the `device not found` and the system doesn't boot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That may be a microcode issue. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248769/intel-microcode-3-20200609-0ubuntu0-20-04-0-update-crashes-computer-unable-to-b

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've done some tuning and here's my fix.

1. Make sure that from grub you can access previous versions of your kernel (eg. 5.4.0-31)
2. Install Grub Repair and run it with proposed fix (by accessing the system with a previous version of the kernel)
3. Reboot
4. Install Grub Customizer
5. Copy "quiet splash acpi=off $vt_handoff" and paste in the corresponding line of the kernel 5.4.0-37 script and on the kernel script for the default startup option. Even thought it's the same kernel, grub treat these scripts as different, so a change in the latter won't affect the previous
6. Save the new configuration
7. Run apt update and apt upgrade. You should see a new package called "intel microcode". Proceed with installation
8. Reboot
9. Here, in my case, the battery indicator has been replaced by the I/O icon and the laptop wouldn't switch off anymore
10. Go back to the Grub Customizer. Delete quiet splash acpi=off $vt_handoff from the script for both kernel 5.4.0-37 and the default option
11. Reboot

And...should be solved!

Comment: Thanks @Federico, Team Ubuntu has released the update and that has been fixed.