# Ubuntu doesn't boot and stuck at purple screen

Tags: boot

I'm unable to boot Ubuntu and stuck at purple screen after choosing Ubuntu from GRUB menu.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I selected E from the screen. Then I entered nomodeset in somewhere. But no changes. Please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intel-microcode 3.20200609.0ubuntu0.20.04.0 update crashes computer. Unable to boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248769/intel-microcode-3-20200609-0ubuntu0-20-04-0-update-crashes-computer-unable-to-b)

Answer (score 5):

Did you update lately?

I updated today and was not able to boot afterwards. First, you can try to boot in an older kernel in Advanced Options.

For me, what worked was adding `dis_ucode_ldr`.

It's seems like it occurred from the latest `intel-microcode` update so you can also have a look at topic related to that. Hope it will help you.