# Avoid missing kernel linux-modules-extra-XX-generic when updating kernel

Tags: kernel, updates, unattended-upgrades

I had this issue with sound [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul) after a reboot.
I was missing package `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic`.

Now I rebooted again (I <s>am not sure</s> [think I know](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265489/226614) if I also rebooted at some point in between), and I had no sound or wifi.
I checked and now I have kernel `5.4.0-42.46`, and I didn't have `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic`.
So I guessed there was an automatic kernel update (I don't recall doing it myself), without installing that package, waiting for me to reboot and suffer from the missing package.

My questions are:

1. Why would an automatic kernel update not install `linux-modules-extra`?
2. Can I configure my system to have the package installed whenever an update takes place?

Related:

[Kernel modules missing after update to 5.4.0-37](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248747/kernel-modules-missing-after-update-to-5-4-0-37)

[What is the linux-image-extra package for and do I need it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153023/what-is-the-linux-image-extra-package-for-and-do-i-need-it)

Comment: is package linux-generic on your system? `apt list --installed | egrep '^linux'
`

Comment: @nobody - I have no package linux-generic. It [seems to have](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/linux-generic/filelist) only two doc files:
`changelog.gz`, 
`copyright`.
Why do you ask?

Answer (score 11):

You need to have `linux-generic` meta package installed.

It will pull all other necessary kernel packages including `modules`, `modules-extra`, `headers`, etc.

This package may be missing if you manually removed some kernel packages.

To fix issues with missing kernel packages run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Comment: Do I also need linux-generic-hwe?

Comment: At the moment there is no difference between `linux-generic` and `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. It will make difference in the future when HWE kernels appear.

Comment: It makes a difference with kernel 5.8.0 - without `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` one needs to manually install `linux-modules-extra` after each kernel upgrade.

Comment: With kernel `5.8.0-43`, I have now installed `linux-generic` and `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`.
I will wait until the next update to confirm whether everything gets updated automatically.

Comment: I confirm I need `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` as discussed. I wonder if the answer should be edited, but I feel this package is specific to 20.04 so maybe a more generic answer is required. Without this metapackage, Kernel updates break my networking, which means I can't get online to read this post nor download the required packages. It seems that Ubuntu's `it should just work` mantra is becoming a more and more distant memory.

Comment: This was the solution for me, I also had to install the corresponding `linux-modules-...` and `linux-modules-extra-...`, for me: `sudo apt install linux-modules-5.15 .0-56-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-56-generic`

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens when a system that was upgraded, but the hardware modules got moved to the HWE layer. APT will keep the auto-install marked for the `linux-generic` meta package, but you need it to instead use `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` meta, so that `linux-modules-extra-...` and `linux-headers-generic-hwe...` are installed automatically.

Fix it by running

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04`

Answer (score 0):

Can you help me work out how I should modify the above suggstions to work in my case? I've the same issue that each time the kernel updates I have to reinstall the appropriate modules-extra package. The package I missed most recently was `linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1032-raspi` when updating from 1030-raspi. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1032-raspi aarch64). So it's not the generic version I need I guess, but perhaps raspi?

So do I need something like `sudo apt install linux-raspi-hwe-22.04.2` or `sudo apt install linux-raspi-22.04.2` or simply `sudo apt install linux-raspi` to force the modules-extra package to update automatically with each update?

After trying the above three options (unsuccessfully - see comments below) I tried `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi` (see https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+question/700375) and at least something installed this time. Fingers crossed this works for the next kernel update.

Comment: OK - so some trial and error. Not the simplest one, the third option:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install linux-raspi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-raspi is already the newest version (5.15.0.1032.29).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.

Comment: Nor the middle option:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install linux-raspi-22.04.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-raspi-22.04.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-raspi-22.04.2'

Comment: Nor the hwe version either:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install linux-raspi-hwe-22.04.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-raspi-hwe-22.04.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-raspi-hwe-22.04.2'