# When was my kernel updated and installed

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, log

This question is related to [Avoid missing kernel linux-modules-extra-XX-generic when updating kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265137/avoid-missing-kernel-linux-modules-extra-xx-generic-when-updating-kernel)

The process of updating the kernel takes several steps.
My questions are:

1. Among all possible ways to update the kernel (e.g., https://ostechnix.com/different-ways-to-update-linux-kernel-for-ubuntu/ and perhaps others not listed), how can I tell which was used in my system?
   I actually mean to confirm if it came from an automatic update (`unattended-upgrades`, or else?)
2. How can I tell when did each of the steps that led to the new kernel be current happen (install kernel packages, reboot, etc.)?
   I mean to do some "forensics".

Comment: Start with your logs: /var/log/apt and /var/log/unattended-upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I list the info I could collect, and how.
Below, the details.

1. How each package was installed (which method, automatic/manual).

   With `apt list --installed | egrep '^linux' | grep $(uname -r)`.
2. When and how each package was installed.

   With `grep $(uname -r)` on `/var/log/apt/history.log*` (I copied and `sudo gunzip`ped somwhere else to keep clean).
3. When each package was installed.

   With `grep $(uname -r)` on `/var/log/dpkg.log*`.
4. When the PC was rebooted.
   I do not know if this info is complete (e.g., covering shutdowns from power outages, etc.)

   With `grep reboot` on `/var/log/kern.log*`. This gave the date/time of reboots, along with numbers [    0.18????] which I do not know what they mean.

   With `grep reboot` on `/var/log/dmesg*`. This gave just the last of the reboots in `kern.log*` (one per file, so I guess each file starts at reboot), along with only numbers [    0.18????].

   With `grep reboot` on `/var/log/syslog*`. This gave a few less reboots than `dmesg*`, along date/time.

   `grep shutdown` on `/var/log/syslog*` did not give any more info.

---

**How each package was installed (which method, automatic/manual)**

From `apt list --installed | egrep '^linux' | grep $(uname -r)` I get 4 packages:

```
linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.4.0-42.46 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.4.0-42.46 amd64 [installed]
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.4.0-42.46 amd64 [installed]
linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.4.0-42.46 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

This shows the kernel was automatically updated.

---

**When and how each package was installed**

Grepping `/var/log/apt/history.log*`.

```
$ grep -B 4 -A 4 -nH $(uname -r) /var/log/apt/history.log
...
/var/log/apt/history.log-67-Start-Date: 2020-08-06  18:34:47
/var/log/apt/history.log:68:Commandline: apt-get install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
/var/log/apt/history.log-69-Requested-By: user1 (1000)
/var/log/apt/history.log:70:Install: linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-42.46)
/var/log/apt/history.log-71-End-Date: 2020-08-06  18:35:41
...
$ grep -B 4 -A 4 -nH $(uname -r) history.log.1
...
history.log.1-208-Start-Date: 2020-07-22  06:26:33
history.log.1-209-Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
history.log.1:210:Install: linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-42.46, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-42.46, automatic), linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-42.46, automatic)
history.log.1-211-Upgrade: linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0-40.44, 5.4.0-42.46)
history.log.1-212-End-Date: 2020-07-22  06:27:05
...
$ grep -B 4 -A 4 -nH $(uname -r) history.log.2
```

---

**When each package was installed**

Grepping `/var/log/dpkg.log*`.

```
$ grep -B 6 -A 5 -nH $(uname -r) /var/log/dpkg.log
...
/var/log/dpkg.log-318-2020-08-06 18:34:48 startup archives unpack
/var/log/dpkg.log:319:2020-08-06 18:34:54 install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 <none> 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:320:2020-08-06 18:34:54 status half-installed linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:321:2020-08-06 18:35:00 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log-322-2020-08-06 18:35:00 startup packages configure
/var/log/dpkg.log:323:2020-08-06 18:35:00 configure linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log:324:2020-08-06 18:35:00 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:325:2020-08-06 18:35:01 status half-configured linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:326:2020-08-06 18:35:05 status installed linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:327:2020-08-06 18:35:05 status triggers-pending linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:328:2020-08-06 18:35:05 trigproc linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log:329:2020-08-06 18:35:05 status half-configured linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log:330:2020-08-06 18:35:41 status installed linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46

$ grep -B 6 -A 5 -nH $(uname -r) /var/log/dpkg.log.1
...
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3123:2020-07-22 06:26:33 install linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 <none> 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3124:2020-07-22 06:26:33 status half-installed linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3125:2020-07-22 06:26:36 status unpacked linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3126:2020-07-22 06:26:36 install linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 <none> 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3127:2020-07-22 06:26:36 status half-installed linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3128:2020-07-22 06:26:37 status unpacked linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3129:2020-07-22 06:26:38 install linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 <none> 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3130:2020-07-22 06:26:38 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3131:2020-07-22 06:26:39 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3132-2020-07-22 06:26:39 upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-40.44 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3133-2020-07-22 06:26:39 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-40.44
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3134-2020-07-22 06:26:39 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-40.44
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3135-2020-07-22 06:26:39 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-40.44
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3136-2020-07-22 06:26:39 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3137-2020-07-22 06:26:39 startup packages configure
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3138:2020-07-22 06:26:39 configure linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3139:2020-07-22 06:26:39 status unpacked linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3140:2020-07-22 06:26:39 status half-configured linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3141:2020-07-22 06:26:40 status installed linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3142:2020-07-22 06:26:40 configure linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3143:2020-07-22 06:26:40 status unpacked linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3144:2020-07-22 06:26:40 status half-configured linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3145:2020-07-22 06:26:41 status installed linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3146:2020-07-22 06:26:41 status triggers-pending linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3147:2020-07-22 06:26:41 configure linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3148:2020-07-22 06:26:41 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3149:2020-07-22 06:26:41 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3150:2020-07-22 06:26:43 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3151-2020-07-22 06:26:43 configure linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3152-2020-07-22 06:26:43 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3153-2020-07-22 06:26:43 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1-3154-2020-07-22 06:26:43 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3155:2020-07-22 06:26:43 trigproc linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3156:2020-07-22 06:26:43 status half-configured linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:3157:2020-07-22 06:27:04 status installed linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic:amd64 5.4.0-42.46
...
```

Comment: that's very elaborate and helpful. thanks