# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes during shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown, freeze

I recently set up Ubuntu 22.04 on my MSI laptop running Windows 11 as a dual boot. The Ubuntu portion is running on my second SSD, so the two OS's are running each on their own drive. When I shutdown or restart the Ubuntu OS it goes to the splash screen and immediately freezes and fails to shutdown completely. If I press F1 during the shutdown, this is what I see, but it seems things are shutting down fine. Are there any additional troubleshooting steps that I should try?

[image]

Running an MSI GE66 Raider Laptop with an intel i7-10750, 32GB RAM and an Nvidia RTX 3070.

Answer (score 1):

###### In my case

- I have standalone Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on Asus x64 AMD Ryzen 7 5800HS with Radeon Graphics.
- For several days, I faced an ongoing shutdown problem related to the "kvm: exiting hardware virtualization" error. Every time I attempted to shut down the operating system, it would become unresponsive, requiring me to perform manual forceful shutdowns.
- I became aware that my kernel had been upgraded to version 6.2 on August 09, 2023. I confirmed this date using the following script: `grep $(uname -r) /var/log/dpkg.log*`.
- I performed a restoration back to August 08, 2023 using Timeshift. During this restoration, my kernel was listed as "Linux asus 5.19.0-50-generic."
- The issue was resolved following the restoration.

###### Update

- Whenever I roll back to the 5.19.0-50-generic version, my kernel automatically upgrades to 6.2.0-26-generic.
- In response, I've configured GRUB with `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"` to ensure that Ubuntu boots using the older kernel.
- The issue was resolved following the configuration.

###### Note

- It appears that installing the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary, tested) could resolve the issue, but I don't plan to do this at the moment.

###### Reference

- [Askubuntu: When was my kernel updated and installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265489/764239)
- [Askubuntu: How can I boot with an older kernel version? (comment)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393019/764239)
- [Askubuntu: UBUNTU shutdown prevent : kvm exiting hardware virtualization (comment)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1482872/764239)

Comment: I do have the exact problem. How did you performed a restoration back? I don't have a backup in Timeshift

Comment: Hi @AliN11, I'm sorry to hear that. If you have Timeshift installed but can't see your backups, please ensure that you have added the `ppa:teejee2008/timeshift` repository, as suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift/issues/108#issuecomment-1519179280) on the Timeshift issue. If you are attempting to manually revert to an older kernel, you can find a discussion about it in [these comments](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/08/ubuntu-22-04-linux-kernel-6-2) on the OMG! Ubuntu post (although I haven't personally attempted to revert only the kernel myself).