# UBUNTU shutdown prevent : kvm exiting hardware virtualization

Tags: shutdown, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, acpi

i hope you are doing well. this problem has been quite a while but i have been researching a lot and  i don't know what else to do.
Ubuntu doesn't shutdown but keeps getting stopped at message: kvm exiting hardware virtualization.
These are the specifications:

- Laptop: hp victus 16
- OS: dual boot (windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04)
- CPU: amd ryzen 5 6000 series with amd radeon graphics
- GPU: nvidia geforce rtx 3050 ti

The attempts that i have tried are:

- blacklisting kvm, kvm-intel and kvm-amd
- editing grub default linux command by adding `acpi=force`

I don't use the virtual machine because i use docker most of the time.
Updating the BIOS is the last thing i want to do because i don't have any experience with it. Is there any other option that you can give?
Any suggestion helps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, sadly I can't help you easily. But I think it is worth to mention that - as you surely done - searching the internet you'll find that in almost all cases the hint to KVM is actually a red herring. KVM is done exiting and something else blocks now. I've in 5 minutes found people that had SD cards in a reader, bad disks in a system, acpi issues ... none of them blocked at kvm actually. So it might be worth to look further what it could be, maybe increasing verbosity of the kernel might help to see what it is working on. Maybe try `ignore_loglevel`?

Comment: I do have this problem after automatic software update. The laptop doesn't shutdown normally and I should shut it down by holding power button

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by installing the NVIDIA-driver, then my ubuntu shutdown normally.

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly on what you did?

Comment: I can't believe this actually worked. I've tried quite a bit and nothing worked. And then this did. 

There are lots instructions online how to install the drivers. Here is one example ---> https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you all are doing well? Thank you all for the suggestions. I could not find a solution at all except only to use force shutdown by pressing the power button for 3 seconds. This isn't normal. I thought the problem was with docker but after uninstalling it it didn't pose a problem. I have no choice but to reinstall ubuntu from the very beginning. It is not a smart solution but it is best. I don't have anything important in there so i don't mind it.
I believe the problem started when i left the laptop in sleep mode with the docker open and i didn't even put the charger on the laptop and it shutdown immediately. So i guess because the docker didn't shutdown correctly, it might have to do with that. Thank you all again.